# Xcode 6: pdf vector images with transparency

Tags: ios, pdf, xcode6

Xcode 6 now has support for pdf vector-based images in asset catalogs. Is it possible to create pdf vector-based images with transparency?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is certainly possible, I tried adding a PDF as vector based image in a test project, and the backgroundcolor properly showed trough.

What are you having trouble with?

Comment: It works for me too now. I must have done something wrong when exporting the image from Sketch. (And I was confused that Preview.app shows a white background by default)

Comment: In Preview you can toggle the "Show Document Background" in the View menu, but it is indeed very confusing that white is the default. Glad to hear you got it sorted though.